# How to change "Menu Key" to Ctrl

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I know the easy ways to remap caps lock, etc, but I haven't found out how to change my <kbd>Menu</kbd> key to be an additional <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. Anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it!

Maco was close. The solution is (in `.Xmodmap`):

```
remove Control = Control_R
keycode 135 = Control_R Control_R Control_R Control_R
add Control = Control_R
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm kinda guessing based on how I've remapped Caps Lock before, but...

Create a `~/.Xmodmap` file containing:

```
clear 135
keycode 135 = Control_R
```

I'm using 135 because that's the keycode xev told me on my keyboard when I hit menu.  Yours may vary.  Log out & back in to take effect.

`setxkbmap -option ctrl:menu` may work if this doesn't.

Comment: No dice. The clear errors it. When I just try:
keycode 135 = Control_R Control_R Control_R Control_R

It is labelled Control_R in xev, but is a "bad key" in control modifier when I 
xmodmap -pm

I've looked around and tried things for most of the morning. Still no success.